# Kafka Broker Application Disconnecting with EOFException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm running an application that connects to the kafka broker using confluentinc/cp-server:7.2.1 docker image.

When I try to run a larger application it just disconnect both application and I need to restart broker.

The message of application is this:

> WARN 16756 --- [RMADE-738-0-C-1]
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer01] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092)
> could not be established. Broker may not be available.
>
> INFO 16756 --- [RMFDE-603-0-C-1]
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer
> clientId=consumer01] Node 1 disconnected.

And the message of broker (docker image) is this:

> broker | INFO Skipping goal violation detection due to previous new
> broker change
> (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.detector.GoalViolationDetector)
>
> [2023] DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1]
> Connection with /172.18.0.1
> (channelId=172.18.0.5:9092-172.18.0.1:51368-43) disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
>
> java.io.EOFException    at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:97)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:797)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:700)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:783)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:635)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:519)
> at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:1463)    at
> kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:1307)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)    at
> org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread.run(KafkaThread.java:64)
>
> [2023] DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1]
> Connection with /172.18.0.1
> (channelId=172.18.0.5:9092-172.18.0.1:50998-29) disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
>
> java.io.IOException: Broken pipe    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:462)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.write(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:143)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.write(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.ByteBufferSend.writeTo(ByteBufferSend.java:62)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkSend.writeTo(NetworkSend.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.write(KafkaChannel.java:728)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.write(Selector.java:753)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptWrite(Selector.java:743)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:652)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:519)
> at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:1463)    at
> kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:1307)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)    at
> org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread.run(KafkaThread.java:64)

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.2.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xms6G -Xmx6G
      JAVA_OPTS: -Xms6G -Xmx6G
      JVM_OPTS: Xmx6g -Xms6g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KAFKA_TOOLS_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.2.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

Comment: Please show your Docker (Compose?) file / run script

Comment: Adding docker-compose.yml

Comment: Can you try with an environment variable `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092` to the Kafka container? Also, you may want to upgrade to a newer version such as 7.3.1

Comment: Did you find what's wrong here? I see a similar issue with my setup.

Comment: Im my case was configuration problem, I will try to find what configuration. But it can be lack of memory.